# get url after redirect with stringWithContentsOfURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, redirect

```
    NSString* HTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&enc error:&error];
```

works great, but if there is a redirect I need to know the url of the redirected page.

Any ideas?

Thanks~~

Comment: Where are you using this urlString ( HTML ) is it in UIWebView or in NSURLConnection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to use NSURLConnection and load manually rather than using the stringWithContesOfURL method. Then you can set a URLConnectionDelegate on your connection.  When you get redirected, the connection will call this method on your delegate:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
```

The request argument provides the URL that you are being redirected to. You can inspect it and do what you want with it. If you want to allow the redirect to continue then you should return it from your delegate's method.

Comment: I'd like to be able to do it synchronously, but NSURLConnection does not seem to allow that AND give me the redirect URL... Also, the NSURLConnection expects me to be able to figure out the encoding, any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Getting the redirect information is *almost* certainly going to require an async call if you use NSURLConnections. You might look into one of the 3rd party libraries to see if they provide something that does what you want.

Comment: As far as figuring out the encoding, if you don't know what it is before you make the request, you can always look at the Content-Type header in the HTTP response and if it is set use that to determine the encoding. If it is not set you will probably need to assume some default value.

Comment: The use of blocks greatly defeat using delegates nowadays. Is there a synchronous and/or block based API for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go (synchronous approach):

```
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL_STRING"]];
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(%@,response.URL);
```

Comment: Works like a charm.. Just a correction, you may not required to use NSMutableURLRequest, You may achieve the same with NSURLRequest. However, the key is capturing the returningResponse.