# Handle wifi issue with stringWithContentOfUrl

Tags: ios, wifi

While testing my application, i connected to a wifi network which needed an authentication to access the internet.
I would have like `[NSString stringWithContentOfUrl:encoding:error:]` to fail or return the content of this authentication page even if it is not the page I asked. But it keeps on trying to download, and never returns.
Do you have any solution to detect this kind of issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `NSURLConnection`. When a redirect happens it will call the delegate method as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395817/get-url-after-redirect-with-stringwithcontentsofurl). Also with `NSURLConnection` you will have greater control in the future when you add additional features and content. Or should the router not do a redirect and just force you to a page, you will be able to use the `NSURLConnection` to download the content and parse it to determine if it is indeed the page you were looking for.

Comment: I understand from your answers that there's no way to handle this within the `stringWithContentOfUrl:` method. What I thought at first, but I preferred ask before changing my method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you'll have to do some coding. Download the contents of the url via NSURLRequest -> NSURLConnection. Then via the NSURLConnection's delegate methods you can respond to the authentication challenge.